Shiny textInput populated with a list and capable of prediction
I need to add a textInput to a Shiny app that does a similar job to what this text box does. It needs to be populated with a long list of locations/coordinates and be able to predict the name of the locations based on what user types. Ideally, it would show a scrollbar too.
See the example
selectInput(inputId = 'locations_coords,label = 'Coordinates',choices = c("John Doe","Ash","Ajay    sharma","Ken Chong","Will Smith","Neo"),selected = NULL,multiple = F)
EDIT:
How can I use a data.frame (like the following example, but much larger) to populate the selectInput in a way that cities are grouped by States and Lat or Long are used as valueField?
cities <- c("Dalby", "Adelaide", "Albury", "Aldgate")
latitudes <- c(-32.8400, -34.9275, -36.0806, -35.0172)
longitudes <- c(151.3800, 138.6000, 146.9158, 138.7377)
states <- c("Queensland", "South Australia", "New South Wales", "South 
Australia")

city_data <- data.frame(
    City = cities,
    Lat = latitudes,
    Long = longitudes,
    LongLat = paste(longitudes, latitudes, sep = ","),
    State = states
)


You could use selectizeInput with its 'create' option active:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(inputId = "test", 
                 label = "Test",
                 choices = c("", month.name),
                 selected = "",
                 options = list(create = TRUE,
                                createOnBlur = TRUE,
                                placeholder = "Test...",
                                persist = TRUE,
                                plugins = list('restore_on_backspace')
                 )
                 
  )  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)

PS: also check the selectize.js plugins

Thanks for the code. How can I make use of a dataframe for choices? And how can I make sure user can still input their own entry (instead of just being able to select from a list)?

This is what I did on the server side, and it does work (locations is a data.frame):
updateSelectizeInput(inputId=id_paddock_settings_coords, label='test label', choices=NULL, selected=NULL,
options=list(create=T, createOnBlur=T, persist=T, plugins=list('restore_on_backspace'), options=locations,
optgroupField='State', labelField='City', searchField='City', valueField='LongLat',
placeholder="Decimal longitude/latitude e.g. 151.26,-27.23", server=T)

hello? Can you please help me out?

@BrianCollins have you tried running the above code? The user is able to create entries not in the list. Regarding the data.frame please provide a proper example.

Hi @ismirsehregal. An example was added to the initial question.

Hi @ismirsehregal. An example was added to the initial question.

This is close to the example you linked to:
  selectInput("state", "Choose a state:", selectize = TRUE,
              choices = c("", list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                              `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                              `Midwest` = c("MN", "WI", "IA"))
                   )

You can't use selected = NULL - the workaround is adding "" as the first option in your choices. I'm not sure whether you need the number included on the right hand side?

This is what I answered 10 minutes ago.

Well I'd already started answering hadn't I. And also, your answer does not deal with the section headings which is part of the question.

The section headings are not needed to answer the question. Just unnecessary fluff.
